# javascript show saved text area with spaces

Tags: javascript

I have a text area that a user can type in then with a button it gets displayed. When they add spaces I get in error in the JavaScript though because its all not on the same line. Is there a way to display the new lines with a JavaScript button press?

```
$(button).click(function(){
    $(DisplayUserTextArea).html('<p> <%= @user.TextArea %> </p>');
});
```

This what happens when it runs on the site and its getting an error here because its spaced out.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
$(button).html('<p> Test Text </p>


<p>TESTTTTTTT</p>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backtick (`) symbol instead of '
For example:

```
$(button).html(`<p> Test Text </p>


<p>TESTTTTTTT</p>`);
```